# Mobile Broadband in Network Manager

Tags: 16.04, network-manager, mobile-broadband, nokia

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and using a mobile broadband Internet connection over a Nokia E51 cellphone. Now the phone died and I wanted to get another dumb phone (no smartphone!). But I don't know how to figure out what is needed in the phone to be working as a modem? Specifically I am looking at the Nokia 3310 3g.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i'm not sure if nokia3310 3g can be used as a modem. And there are 3 ways to use it as a modem a. via usb cable, b. via wifi if the phone supports wifi hotspot, c. via bluetooth tethering if supported. The only way to use this phone as a modem is via usb cable as i'm not sure that supports wifi hotspot or bluetooth tethering.
You rather should check phone's manual or contact nokia.

But why don't you buy a usb mobile modem (3g/4g dongle) from your mobile provider?
It's the best solution especially now that 3g/ 4g speeds are sometimes faster than adsl.

Comment: Nokia 3310 3g is unfortunately not supporting tethering. The reason why I dont want a usb-dongle is that my (prepaid) contract includes 2GB of data, way more than I need, and I dont want a) a second SIM or b) another contract, since I only use the data very occasionally.
Workaround: Bought a secondhand Nokia C5.